# Real Time mySQL, PHP Google Maps API Update

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have an android app sending gps coordinates in a 1 sec. Interval to php and then mysql on a server. Them i have a site where location of the device can be tracked in real time on google maps. The problem is that when i call the php script to query new coordinates in mysql, it runs perfect the first time and gives me the latest coordinates to use on google maps,  but after the first loop , it keep on givimg me the same value , even if the database has been updated.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Horse Tracker © 2013 Abiapps</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript"src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?********&sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="map.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    </head>

<body>
    <h1>Horse Tracker © 2013 Abiapps </h1>
    <input type="button" value="getValues" id="getValues" />
    <input type="button" value="changeValues" id="changeValues" />
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
    (function() {
    window.onload = function() {

        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.694094,23.683620);
        var options = {
            center: latlng,
            zoom: 4,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

            mapTypeControl: true,
            navigationControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
            },
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
            },
            streetViewControl: false,
            backgroundColor: '#0000ff'

        };




        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, options);
            document.getElementById('getValues').onclick = function() {
            alert('Current Zoom level is ' + map.getZoom());
            alert('Current center is ' + map.getCenter());
            }

            document.getElementById('changeValues').onclick = function() {
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php include 'getgps.inc.php';?>);
            map.setCenter(latLng);
            }

            var a = 1;
            function autoUpdate() {
            a = a;
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php include 'getgps.inc.php';?>);
            map.setCenter(latLng);
            alert('<?php include 'getgps.inc.php';?>');
            setTimeout(autoUpdate, 1000);
            }

        autoUpdate();
    }
})();


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

and the php code..

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; 
$username="*****"; 
$password="*****"; 
$db_name="horsetrack"; 
$tbl_name="gps"; // 
 $body = "";
// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server ");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $id = $rows['id'];
        $datetime = $rows["datetime"];
        $Rname = $rows["rider"];
        $Rlat = $rows["lat"];
        $Rlng = $rows["lng"];

$body = $Rlat.','.$Rlng;
}
echo $body;

mysql_close(); //close database
?>
```

im getting the same result in alert(); as the firt query even if i add row to the database

Answer (score 2):

You realize that your PHP code is executed on the server, not the client? When this line is executed:

```
 alert('<?php include 'getgps.inc.php';?>');
```

you'll end up with something like

```
 alert('foo');
```

embedded the javascript you send over to the client. When your `autoUpdate()` function is executed in the client, the PHP code is **LONG** since gone and **NEVER** re-executed by the client, so that `'foo'` text never changes.

You need to use an AJAX call to fetch a FRESH copy of that file's output each time, not simply re-alert what was embedded in the page when it was generated.

Comment: there's tons of ajax questions/answers on this site, and plenty of googleable tutorials.